# Can we declare multiple variables on one line in a UML class diagram?

Tags: uml

```
private int x1, x2, y1, y2;
```

Can the UML line be:

```
- x1,x2,y1,y2: int
```

Or do we have to make them on 4 separate lines?

Comment: What do you mean, "the UML"? What part of UML are you referring to?

Comment: The class UML where you put the variables http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram

Answer (score 4):

You are referring to a UML Class Diagram.

That means that you are not referring to variables. You are referring to *attributes*.

UML Class Diagrams do not contain "lines". They are a graphical depiction of a UML class model. The model includes a list of attributes. The class diagram displays the set of attributes.

I have never seen an implementation of UML which displays multiple attributes on the same row of a class diagram.

Comment: Ok, i will make 4 separate lines.

Comment: @user83039 See also http://www.uml-diagrams.org/property.html and "general syntax for properties"

Answer (score 1):

The UML standard has examples for all noticeably different kinds of attributes. As you can see, there no possibility for several attributes in one line.

[image]

```
ClassA::name is an attribute with type String.
ClassA::shape is an attribute with type Rectangle.
ClassA::size is a public attribute of type Integer with multiplicity 0..1.
ClassA::area is a derived attribute with type Integer. It is marked as read-only.
ClassA::height is an attribute of type Integer with a default initial value of 5.
ClassA::width is an attribute of type Integer.
ClassB::id is an attribute that redefines ClassA::name.
ClassB::shape is an attribute that redefines ClassA::shape. It has type Square, a specialization of Rectangle.
ClassB shows size as an attribute inherited from ClassA, as signified by the prepended caret symbol (see 9.2.4).
ClassB::height is an attribute that redefines ClassA::height. It has a default of 7 for ClassB instances that overrides the ClassA default of 5.
ClassB::width is a derived attribute that redefines ClassA::width, which is not derived.
```

http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/ - I strongly advice to use the 2.5 version, even if it is in beta2 version. I is absolutely the same as accepted 2.4.1 as for content (officially), but differs in the ways of explanation - is much easier.

Comment: In [OMG Unified Modeling Language™ (OMG UML), Superstructure, Version 2.4.1](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/Superstructure/PDF/) document the above example can be found as `Figure 7.30`

Comment: It is the 2.5 beta. If we are looking for some extra possibilities, failing to use the last possible source would be a mistake, IMHO. BTW, I strongly advice to use the 2.5 version, that is absolutely the same as 2.4.1 as for content (officially), but differs in the ways of explanation - is much easier.

Comment: @Cangnus Ok, IMO providing a link to the latest official version of the "UML standard" is better then providing no link at all. If OP needs to ask very basic notation questions here then OP probably does not know where to find it elsewhere

Comment: @xmojmr You are right. Edited. Sorry for my laziness.